# cmake cannot find CUDA when installing opencv on ubuntu

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I have installed CUDA 8.0 on ubuntu and set the environment variable in .bashrc as below:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin
```

Also, when I run 
    nvcc --version
I can find the correct version of CUDA.
However, it always shows "use cuda: NO" when I try to run "cmake .." inside opencv 3.3 directory.

Can anyone solve this problem? Thanks.

ps: 
1. When I compile caffe, cmake can find CUDA correctly. It gets more confusing.
2. When I check OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake, I found the following phrase sentence:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT APPLE AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
  message(STATUS "CUDA compilation is disabled (due to Clang unsupported on your platform).")
  return()
endif()
```

Then I comment this paragraph, cmake can find CUDA. I am not sure what effect it will cause in later compilation and use.

Comment: This is an OpenCV build question, not a CUDA programming question, which is why I removed the tag. Please don't re-add it

Answer (score 0):

If building from source is giving you as issue try installing via pip:

---

$ pip install opencv-python

I suspect the reason why you are having issues with building your opencv is because of the source of your files.